# How to prove that any discrete set without limit points in the plane maps to the integers via ambient isotopy? Which extension theorem to cite?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology, education

**Questions.**

(0) What are *efficient reasons* for: any discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ **without limit points** can be mapped by a *plane isotopy* to the pointset $\{ (x,0)\colon x\in\mathbb{Z}\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$?

(1) Is it **true or false** that: any *countably-infinite* subset of $\mathbb{S}^2$ with precisely *one* limit point can be mapped by an *ambient isotopy of the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$* to the pointset $\{ (\cos(\frac{2\pi}{r}),\sin(\frac{2\pi}{r}),0)\colon r\in\mathbb{Z}, r>0 \}\subseteq\mathbb{S}^2$?

**Remarks.**

- The questions thelselves should be complete without further explanations.
- One obvious sort-of-conceptual approach to (0) would be to say something like '$\mathbb{R}^2\setminus S$ is homeomorphic to 'the' surface with countably-many and discretely-spaced punctures.", yet I neither found a citable reference useful to answer the question proper, nor found it useful to bring in the concept of 'surface' here wwhen explaining/justifying this to someone else.
- I think I could work out a proof myself, yet I would prefer a precise citable **reference** in the published literature. This is such an intuitively evident and elementary statement that it seems likely that it occurs several times in the literature.
- To me, the *obvious* approach to (0) seems this. Given any discrete set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$, $S$ is necessarily countable, so there is an bijection $p\colon I\rightarrow S$, $i\mapsto p_i$, with $I$ an at most countably infinite set.

We may assume w.l.o.g. that $S$ is countably *infinite*, and that $I=\mathbb{Z}$.

One then can of course define the map

$\vartheta\colon S\times [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ given by

for all $i\in\mathbb{Z}$, for all $t\in[0,1]$, $\qquad\theta(p_i,t) = (1-t)\cdot p_i + t\cdot i$

and one now needs a precise reference to a *suitable extension theorem* which would guarantee an *extension* of $\vartheta$ to a plane isotopy $\theta\colon\mathbb{R}^2\times[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$. In this sense, a variant question whose answer would be:

- What is a right extension theorem to extend the above $\theta$? For obvious reasons, the right direction seem to be known statements about continous maps of the form $[0,1]^{\omega}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. 
  What do you consider the most standard theorem and reference to cite here?
- While *plane isotopy* is a very usual term, here is a definition, copied from [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278009/how-to-prove-that-there-does-not-exist-any-plane-isotopy-from-the-logarithmic-sp), a question which is related to the motivation for this question (an open problem about infinite planar graphs)

  - Let

$\eta_S\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$,

and

$\eta_R\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$,

be *arbitrary* set-maps (for the purposes of the discrete sets, we could of course restrict to *piecewise continuous*, or even *piecewise differentiable* maps)

Then a *plane isotopy* from $\eta_S$ to $\eta_R$ is any continuous set-map

$\theta\colon \mathbb{R}^2\times[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$

satisfying the three axioms

(A.0) for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $v=\theta(v,0)$,

(A.1) for all $t\in[0,1]$, $v\mapsto\theta(v,t)$ defines a *homeomorphism* $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$,

(A.2) $(v\mapsto \theta(v,1))\circ\eta_S = \eta_R$, equal as set-maps.

- I would appreciate both references to the question proper, and *references to extension statements* appropriate to the evident 'write-down-the-isotopy' approach. It should be easily be provable that one can ' extend $\vartheta$ 'piecewise-linearly' to a plane isotopy $\mathbb{R}^2\times[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ ' , yet there should be a better approach than try to do this explicitly by hand.
- Are there relevant references on (0) and (1) from the published literature on [configuration spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space)?

Comment: Google "classification of noncompact surfaces".

Comment: Your statement in (0) is wrong, the correct statement is that any **closed** discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be mapped by a plane isotopy to $\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\} = \{(x,0) : x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Without requiring "closed", the set $\{(\frac{1}{x},0) : x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a counterexample, being discrete, and not having any such isotopy.

Comment: @LeeMosher: thanks for pointing out. I forget to add "without limit points" (which implies 'closed'). I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the 1963 paper by I.Richards ["On the classification of noncompact surfaces"](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-106-02/S0002-9947-1963-0143186-0/S0002-9947-1963-0143186-0.pdf). It takes some time to get through the terminology, but the "ideal boundary" he is talking about (or "the spaces of ends") in your examples is exactly the discrete subset of $R^2$  (there is no difference between questions 0 and 1). More generally, if $A$ is a compact totally disconnected subset of $S^2$, then $S$ is homeomorphic to the space of ends of the surface $S^2-A$. The conclusion is that if you have two homeomorphic totally disconnected subsets $A, B\subset S^2$, then there is a homeomorphism of pairs $(S^2,A)\to (S^2,B)$. From this, you get an isotopy, since for homeomorphisms of closed surfaces homotopy is equivalent to isotopy. (In the case of the 2-sphere, this is due to Alexander, it is a corollary of  "the Alexander trick").

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this fits your idea of efficient, but problem 0 can be
solved (in $\mathbb{R}^n, n \ge 2$) by fairly simple 
geometry.

Note that there is a $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that no two
points of $S$ have the same distance to $c$. (The set of points for which
this is not the case form a meagre set of measure zero.) By compactness,
every closed ball about $c$ contains finitely many points of $S$, so the
points in $S$ can be enumerated by increasing distance from $c$.
This implies that there is a discrete family of concentric annuli, each
one containing a single point of $S$. Using spherical coordinates it is 
straightforward to construct a suitable isotopy for each of the annuli and
by the pasting lemma these can be combined into an isotopy of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Alternatively, I suppose you could appeal to the path-connectedness of $SO(n)$ to get an interpolation.

I would be surprised if this trick was
not known at least a century ago, but I don't know if anyone ever
bothered to write it down.

For problem 1 you obviously need the additional assumption that the unique
limit point is not in the set. Making that assumption, we can identify $\mathbb{S}^2$ with the one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in
such a way that the limit point corresponds to $\infty$ and then the 
problem can be reduced to the previous one.